# responsive login page (html/css only)

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm working on a responsive login page (open source). Could you try to review a bit the code on Github ?

```css
body{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #ff0000, #ff5600, #ff8000, #ffa200, #ffc200);

}

#title {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#subtitle {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #fff;

}


#title a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.page {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 368px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 48px 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}



.top-box {
    height: 30%;
}
.box form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#user-icon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#email, #password{
    height: 48px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #c0c0c0;
    border-width: thin;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 1px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000000;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 1px #000000;
    width: 100%;

}

#email {
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: hidden;
    
}

#password {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}


#email::placeholder, #password::placeholder {
    color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
}

#submit {
    height: 44px;
    background: rgb(68, 112, 255);
    color: white;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body {
    background: #F7F7F7;
}


.box{
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: 400px;


}
.body  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }


#user-icon {
    display: none;

}
#title a{
    color: black;
}

#title {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 35px;


}
#subtitle {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;

}

}

@media screen and (max-height: 320px) {
    #title {
        font-size: 0;
    }

    #subtitle {
        position: fixed;
        top: 15px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    #title {
        font-size: 0;
    }

    #subtitle {
        font-size: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-height: 600px) {
    #title {
        font-size: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-height: 475px) {
    #subtitle {
        font-size: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Sign in</title>
</head>
<body>
 <span id="title-span"><h1 id="title"><a href="https://github.com/eloisb">Eloi SB</a></h1></span>
 <div class="page"> 
  <h2 id="subtitle">Sign in to continue</h2>
  <div class="body">
  <div class="box">
   <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/6/7e0f9ccff2b62a855e5d611467ce65c9-full.png" alt="" id="user-icon">
   <form class="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" id="submit">
   </form>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[https://github.com/eloisb/login_page/](https://github.com/eloisb/login_page)

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

It's invalid HTML to have `h1` inside `span`.

Don't use IDs for general styling use classes instead (see for example https://dev.to/claireparkerjones/reasons-not-to-use-ids-in-css-4ni4).

Regarding the HTML structure it seems to make sense to have the title inside the `.page` element.

Many of the used id and class names are very generic. Considering this is a login page I would at the very least expect the word "login" to be used somewhere. Have a look at some CSS naming schemes, for example BEM.

It seems to me to be a bad idea to use `font-size: 0` to hide elements. Why not use `display: none`?

The layout breaks for small browser windows heights.

Comment: Thanks, I published a new version on github. But aren't id better for unique elements ?

Answer (score 0):

Your style is that of Google. It's simple and consice. However, I have a few remarks.

1. The [color classes](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/color-theory-for-designers-part-1-the-meaning-of-color/) are in conflict. You have a mix of warm (red) and cold (blue) colors.
2. There is no warning when the user has [Caps Lock](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_detect_capslock.asp) on when typing in the password.
3. You are missing support functions as 'Need help logging in' and 'Stay logged in'.